# Paypal Payments - 500 Error

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to make a automatic payment in my system, and got it to work perfectly in sandbox mode. As soon, as I switch to live mode I am receiving a 500 error. I am not sure if maybe the URL's I've copied are maybe from a legacy site or something.

Here is my params:

[image]

My post back error looks like:

```
{"ClassName":"PayPal.Exception.HttpException","Message":"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":" at PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest httpRequest)\r\n at PayPal.APIService.MakeRequestUsing(IAPICallPreHandler apiCallHandler)\r\n at PayPal.BasePayPalService.Call(IAPICallPreHandler apiCallHandler)\r\n at PayPal.AdaptivePayments.AdaptivePaymentsService.Pay(PayRequest payRequest, String apiUserName)\r\n at Cashbackeroo.Payment.PayPal.PayPalPaymentService.Pay(PaymentRequest paymentRequest)","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nExecute\nPayPalCoreSDK, Version=1.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b4afc1ccaef40fb\nPayPal.HttpConnection\nSystem.String Execute(System.String, System.Net.HttpWebRequest)","HResult":-2146233088,"Source":"PayPalCoreSDK","WatsonBuckets":null}
```

Comment: It looks like you commented out the Sandbox App ID. I could be wrong but you may need to replace it with a Production ID.

In my integration ( using javascript ) I basically had to make a duplicate of everything for both Sandbox and Client; Most importantly the Sandbox and Production ID's.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I included prod id for the placeholder 'applicationId=' I just commented that so I could reference it in future

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Accounts
The Adaptive Accounts API allows you to create and manage PayPal accounts for PayPal users. To make an API call, see Adaptive Accounts API call headers and endpoints.

Adaptive Accounts endpoints
To make Adaptive Accounts API calls. include an AppID with your API credentials.
For sandbox testing, specify an AppID of APP-80W284485P519543T.

API
Formats
Endpoints
Adaptive Accounts
SOAP with XML,
NVP, or JSON
Live
https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/
Sandbox
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the Paypal URL dirrectly in your browser. Does it returns a 500 server error or 200 ok?

Usually when the Paypal servers are down, the response is 500 server error.